# Jenkins returns with Failed to parse POMs

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

Trying to achieve CI using selenium maven jenkins.

But when tried to execute, JENKINS returned with the following error in console

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mvnj/workspace
Parsing POMs
[mvnj] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.5.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/share/maven /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.53.2.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.5.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 46984
 ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java" (in directory "/home/operations/workspace/mvnj"): error=20, Not a directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:266)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:755)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=20, Not a directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 12 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by changing the Java path in Jenkins Configuration. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo? Looks like this directory

```
/home/operations/workspace/mvnj
```

doesnt exist